# Global variable not being parsed inside related_entries tag

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, expressionengine

I've got two channels that are related. The website is multilingual and the `{lang}` global variable contains the language (en / nl / de / fr).

Using the `{{lang}-something}` approach works throughout the whole site, but not within the **related entries** tag.

The output of `{{lang}-something}` **should** be the content, but it literally **is** `{en-something}`. So the language is inserted but it's not being parsed after that.

When I simply use `{en-something}` in the template (without dynamically setting the language) I do get the content.

Template snippet:

```
{related_entries id="product_usp_1"}
    <div class="ups_item">
        <h3>{{lang}-usp-title}</h3>
        <p>{{lang}-usp-content}</p>
    </div>
{/related_entries}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why, but this works:

```
<h3> {<?php echo '{language}';?>-usp-title}   </h3>
<p>  {<?php echo '{language}';?>-usp-content} </p>
```

This code is insite the `related_entries` tag, **not** embedded.

PHP Parsing stage: **input**

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like `{lang}` is parsed pretty late in the process -- see [Low's excellent help](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) on this.  This suggests that you might have joy moving the inner part of your example to an embedded template (a hack I strongly dislike even though it's often deployed!).  So your original bit becomes:

```
{related_entries id="product_usp_1"}
  <div class="ups_item">
    {embed:lang_template}
  </div>
{/related_entries}
```

and the embedded template (`lang_template` above) becomes:

```
<h3>{{lang}-usp-title}</h3>
<p>{{lang}-usp-content}</p>
```

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks so much for your reply. Unfortunately it does **not** work, even though it seems like a good solution the result is exactly the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi Robert:  Sorry that didn't work.  My other idea is a little hand-wavy, but you might consider a plugin that uses `$this->EE->session->userdata('language')` to return what you need.

Comment: Thanks again Scott. I've found a working solution. Not sure why this does work. Any thoughts?